# How to run a command inside a docker container from a jenkins script

Tags: docker, ssl, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

I have a jenkins script that looks like this:

```
    pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'machine'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('GC Open Build') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    docker run -i --rm \
                       -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
                       -e USER_NAME=$(id -un) \
                       -e GROUP_NAME=$(id -gn) \
                       -e HOME \
                       -v $HOME:$HOME \
                       -v /PROJ:/PROJ:shared \
                       -v /srv:/srv \
                       -w $PWD \
                       i-st-pd-docker-vxxxxxx
                       bash | hostname
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It executes successfully, but the hostname it displays is not the docker container, but the machine on which it runs.

If I try with '-t' in the docker run command, then I get "the input device is not a tty":

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'machine'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('GC Open Build') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    docker run -it --rm \
                       -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
                       -e USER_NAME=$(id -un) \
                       -e GROUP_NAME=$(id -gn) \
                       -e HOME \
                       -v $HOME:$HOME \
                       -v /PROJ:/PROJ:shared \
                       -v /srv:/srv \
                       -w $PWD \
                       i-st-pd-docker-v.xxxx
                       bash | hostname
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the input device is not a TTY
ERROR: script returned exit code 1

Any suggestions to be able to run a set of commands (other than "hostname" from inside the docker container?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins has native `Docker` support available for [declarative pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/). So you can either use your `Docker` image as an agent or you can use the Docker step.

**Using the image as an agent.**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'gradle:6.7-jdk11'
                    // Run the container on the node specified at the
                    // top-level of the Pipeline, in the same workspace,
                    // rather than on a new node entirely:
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'gradle --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Using docker step**

```
docker.image('mysql:5').inside("--link ${c.id}:db") {
            /* Wait until mysql service is up */
            sh 'while ! mysqladmin ping -hdb --silent; do sleep 1; done'
        }
```

Comment: is docker not supported for normal jenkins pipeline?